# Linker LNK1112:module machine type 'THUMB' conflicts with target machine type 'ARM' error for Win ce7.0 MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, embedded

I am trying to build a `mfc` application, which was previously built for `Win ce 5.0` using `VS2008`.

I migrated the code from `Win ce 5.0` to `Win CE 6.0` keeping the project settings same for all the projects in the solution.The application was migrated successfully to `Win CE 6.0`.

Now, I am trying to migrate the code to `win Ce 7.0`. I kept all the projects settings same as I did while migrating to `win CE 6.0`, except the `Linker->Input-.additional dependencies:empty`

Previously for `Win CE 5.0` and `Win CE 6.0`, I have added `Linker->Input-.additional dependencies:Ws2.lib`

I am getting the following error:

```
coredll.lib(COREDLL.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'THUMB' conflicts with target machine type 'ARM'
```

My setup is as follows:

> Win XP PC,
>
> Visual studio 2008 professional
>
> Win CE 7.0 SDK installed

I have 10 projects in my solution. 9 projects are static Library projects and one is Application (.exe)

The linker setting was for the application type project.

This is the clear view of the errors and warnings.

```
Linking... 10>LINK : warning LNK4010: invalid subsystem version number
0x700; default subsystem version assumed 10>coredll.lib(COREDLL.dll) :
fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'THUMB' conflicts with target
machine type 'ARM' 10>Project : warning PRJ0018 : The following
environment variables were not found: 10>$(PLATFORMDEFINES)

Rebuild All: 9 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Please help.

Comment: See [Windows CE: fatal error LNK1112](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2009/07/30/windows-ce-fatal-error-lnk1112.aspx).